# unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 in R programming language

Tags: r, rmongodb

```
mangodb<-mongo.create()
```

This my `r` code. When I'm creating a connection, it raises the following error:

```
Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, error code = 2.
```

Answer (score 2):

That means that `mongodb` isn't listening on its default port (27017). Did you start `mongodb`?
The `R` package provides an interface to connect to `mongodb`, but it's your (or the administrator) responsibility to start the `mongodb` daemon.